# Update mysql 32bit to 64bit

Tags: mysql, database, centos

I have like 10 biiiiiiiiiiiiiig mysql datebases and I have mysql 32bit, It can only use 3gb of ram memory... I need more so I need to update the mysql to 64 bit (the server has 32gb of ram memory). How can I update it without loosing data.

I prefer not to make a backup and reupload it because the datebases are very very big...
Is there any alternative?

The OS is centos 5.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have your data in a separate partition, just dont format the partition. You can upgrade your OS and your mysql to 64 bit. then just point your mysql to your data partition.

Comment: I have a 64bit OS. I only need to change the mysql to 64 bit. I have all in the same hdd.

Comment: I think you will not have a problem when you upgrade your mysql. All you need to do is uninstall the mysql 32 bit then install the 64 bit version. Just make sure to have a backup of data incase something went wrong. But base on my experience you should be fine. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The internal format of the MySQL database and files does not change based on architecture, but may change slightly depending on MySQL version. You'll want to switch your OS to 64-bit, update to MySQL 5.6 if you're going through all this trouble.

You **must** make a backup of your data. You won't necessarily need to restore from it, but you cannot just slap on an new OS and assume it'll work out fine.

If your databases are on a separate partition or volume on your system you should be okay to install the OS on the main system partition, reformat that accordingly. Be very careful you don't re-initialize the drive by accident. Once again, this is why backups are essential.

You also don't define what "big" is. For some people that means "a few GB". The database engine also matters. You *should* be using InnoDB.

Comment: All the datebases together are using ~10gb.
Why InnoDB? IDK what it does.
You said "you cannot just slap on an new OS and assume it'll work out fine" but I never said I need to update my OS. Anyway, can I copy "data" folder into another place, then update my mysql to 64 bit, so when I resotre data folder to the right place it should work fine?

Comment: You won't be able to run 64-bit MySQL on a 32-bit OS. You need 64-bit across the board for it to work correctly under Linux. Also 10GB is not a big database, you can copy that across a 1GBit network in minutes. If you're using InnoDB as your storage engine, and you should be (`SHOW TABLE STATUS` will tell you) then you can use the [`innobackupex`](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtrabackup/2.1/innobackupex/innobackupex_script.html) tool to help back up your data properly.

Comment: I never said that I have a 32bit OS. I have a 64bit OS. So, is it possible what I said before?

Comment: You said "I have MySQL 32-bit" which is what you get when you have a 32-bit OS installed. How did you get a 32-bit version of that on a 64-bit CentOS install?

Comment: Doesn't matters. The point is that I have 64bit OS & 32bit MySQL. Is there any way to update it?

Comment: However you got the 32-bit one, you have to remove it, and then you should install the correct one that should've been installed in the first place. CentOS uses `yum`, right?

Comment: Yes it uses yum. Well, if I copy "data" folder to another place, then I remove 32bit mysql, then I install 64bit mysql and finally I replace the data folder with the one I backuped, it should work, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 0):

1. Backup the 32 bit database.
2. Extract the zip distro, not self-installer, for your 64 bit OS (from dev.mysql.com or contract-supplier) to new install directory.
3. Make a copy of existing 32 bit service's .ini file.  Edit it so the port, basedir, datadir, etc are referencing the new, unused values.
4. Restore 32bit backup using 64 bit software - to New datadir.
5. Run the 64bit upgrade command (from the shell) to check table integrity and run schema upgrades.
6. Startup 64bit service.